# JSON data schema allOf $ref external json schema file not working

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, python-jsonschema

I have recently started exploring JSON Schema for one of our project. The use case is very straight forward and after lot of googling I am still not able to make it work. Actually I am little bit lost here.
. This is what I tried https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html

My `common_data_schema.json`

```
{   
 "definitions": {
    "sp_common_data": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "os_ip": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "ipv4"
        },
        "os_user": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "os_pwd": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "remote_os": {
          "default": "Windows",
          "enum": [
            "Linux",
            "Windows"
          ]
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "os_ip",
        "os_user",
        "os_pwd",
        "remote_os"
      ]
    }   },   
    "type": "object",   
    "properties": {
       "sp_must_data":{ "$ref": "#/definitions/sp_common_data" }   
   } 
}
```

Now my `server_update.json` schema , where I want to validate `common_data_schema` + `new` `properties`

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
   "type": "object",
   "properties": {
      "sp_must_data":{"$ref": "common_data_schema.json#sp_common_data"},
      "file": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
```

But when I am trying to validate `server_update.json` schema using `jsonschema` https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ it doesn't consider the `$ref` schema `common_data_schema.json` definitions

The `schema loader` logic is straight forward, all my schemas are residing inside  `artifacts` folder

```
import json
from pathlib import Path

# Location for the test artifacts
artifacts = Path(__file__).parent.parent.joinpath("artifacts").resolve()


def load_schema(filename):
    data = open(Path(artifacts).joinpath(filename), "r").read()
    return json.loads(data)
```

The `json schema` validation logic below

```
from typing import Dict, List
from jsonschema import Draft7Validator, exceptions


def validate(schema: Dict, instance: Dict) -> List[exceptions.ValidationError]:
    """
    Validate the instance using the specified schema

    :param schema: Schema object
    :param instance: instance Object
    :return: List of errors during validation
    """

    validator = Draft7Validator(schema=schema)
    return list(validator.iter_errors(instance))
```

Comment: Most implementation won't automatically fetch schemas from the file system or over http. You have to load the schemas before you can reference them. How this works is implementation specific, so if you share what implementation you are using, someone might know to specific incantations you will need.

Comment: I have used `jsonschema` https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ to validate the JSON schema definitions